# Esiste il modo di dire "stendere secco"? Cosa significa?

Tags: idioms, meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto:

> Mi piaceva. Poi con quelle pecore *mi aveva stesa secca*, non ti nascondo...

Queste frasi sono parte del dialogo nel quale una ragazza parla del suo amico Fil, un brillante studente che fa un master di Economia a Londra. "Con quelle pecore" si riferisce al fatto che, a un certo momento, Fil comincia a lavorare come aiutante di un pastore di pecore.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "mi aveva stesa secca" nel brano precedente. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Qual è il suo significato?

Comment: A occhio direi che intenda “mi aveva tramortita”, “mi aveva lasciata senza parole”, detto di qualcuno che fa qualcosa di sbalorditivo. È compatibile con il contesto?

Comment: @DaG: Di sicuro si tratta di questo. Ho cercato di spiegare un po' di più del contesto, così magari si capisce meglio.

Comment: Potrebbe forse stare per "ha parlato così a lungo di pecore che mi ha ucciso di noia"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: No, non credo che sia questo. Penso che il senso sia quello spiegato da DaG: ai personaggi del romanzo sembra molto sorprendente che Fil prendesse quel lavoro.

Comment: Legherei anche il significato al termine *seccare* inteso come *annoiare*: *Mi sono seccato dei tuoi discorsi*. Per somiglianza c'è anche *asciugare*, forse un po' più dialettale, da usare come fa l'autrice: *Coi suoi discorsi mi ha asciugata*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Stendere secco” = “fulminare”, “sconfiggere”, “uccidere”, “buttare giù”.  Simile, in significato, all'inglese “*(to) knock down*”.

Nell'esempio  citato nella domanda è usato non alla lettera ma in senso figurato, col senso di “mi aveva tramortita”, “mi aveva lasciata senza parole”, detto di qualcuno che fa qualcosa di sbalorditivo

Comment: Qui però ha un senso figurato perché nessuno è ucciso. Qual è questo senso?

Comment: Sì, certo, in questo caso sì.

Comment: Penso che il senso figurato sia quello spiegato da @DaG, ma si dovrebbe aggiungere alla risposta.

Comment: Mi sono permesso di aggiungerlo, Orlando.

Comment: @DaG: Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto l'espressione "restare secco" che immagino significhi lo stesso.

Comment: @DaG: Ecco il brano: «Quand’ecco uscire dalla casa il contadino e sfangare verso
la stalla, ancora fantomatico nella luce che cresceva a fiotti
grigi. Milton stava strusciandosi il mento e il fruscio quasi
metallico della barba lunga e rada si diffondeva per metri
all’intorno. Infatti il contadino guardò su e **restò secco**. –
Hai passato la notte lassú?» (ortografia di Einaudi).

Comment: Il contadino non sapeva che Milton aveva dormito nel suo fienile ed è rimasto sbalordito, senza parole quando l'ho ha scoperto.

Answer (score 0):

Interpretando il passo citato, "stava stesa secca", vuol dire che lei, di fianco alle suddette pecore, giaceva rilassata. In italiano "fare secco qualcuno" è equivalente a dire "uccidere qualcuno", perciò l'autore voleva sottolineare l'immobilitá del soggetto narrato.

Comment: No, no, @Leonardo! Qui non viene ucciso nessuno, te lo posso assicurare!

Comment: Io non ho parlato di uccisioni, ho detto che visto che il soggetto giaceva talmente fisiologicamente rilassato a terra, l'autore usando "secco" sottolineava l'immobilità del tale, facendo un paragone macrabo con un cadavere; non ho mai detto che si trovava a terra morta, ma solo che "giaceva rilassata".

Comment: Comunque, non credo che si riferisca a essere stesa accanto alle pecore in senso letterale. La ragazza parla di suo amico Fil e afferma che è rimasta "stesa secca" quando ha saputo che Fil lavorava con le pecore.